# Terraform random_string as password for linux machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to use this to generate a random password for the linux machines in gcp.

My question is how I get the password afterwards.
Should I use the output for this or is it stored anywhere else?
I saw this code on the internet and was asking myself how they know the password then.

```
resource "random_string" "master_password" {
  length  = 16
  special = true
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
  name               = "test"
  zone               = "europe-west1-d"

  master_auth {
    username = "client"
    password = "${random_string.master_password.result}"
  }

  node_pool = [{
    name       = "pool"
    autoscaling = {
      min_node_count = 1
      max_node_count = 3
    }

    node_config {
      disk_size_gb = 100
      machine_type = "n1-standard-2"

      oauth_scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      ]

      labels {
        test = "true"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The password will be stored in your state file. You can go digging around in there for it, but it is entirely possible that it's exact location in the file will change between Terraform versions.

The best way to get a consistent output is to, as you mentioned, use an output block. Then when you do a `terraform apply` there will be a nice human readable output of this password. Please note that anything with access to your state has access to that password, so keep the state secure.

If you use remote state (such as in an S3 bucket), you can also use [terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) to gain access to this from another Terraform run. You will need to explicitly `output` values you want to be available from `terraform_remote_state`.

Finally, be aware that if something captures the output of your `terraform apply`, it will also capture that output since `terraform apply` writes to STDOUT. This might happen if you use a CI tool. Just something to be aware of.